# Turning a dictionary with one key and multiple values to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How I can turn this dictionary into a pandas dataframe?

```
dict = {'key1':['value1','value2'], 'key2':['value1','value2', 'value3'], 'key3':['value1','value2', 'value3', 'value4'] }
```

I have tried both:

`pd.Dataframe(dict)` and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`

but I get the same error.

`ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

So, it looks that the built-in possibilities only work for `balanced` dictionaries.

Any help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, it looks that the built-in possibilities only work for balanced dictionaries.

[`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) can be used with uneven dictionaries by setting `orient='index'`:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

#            0       1       2       3
# key1  value1  value2    None    None
# key2  value1  value2  value3    None
# key3  value1  value2  value3  value4
```

---

To get the transposed version, chain `.T`:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T

#      key1    key2    key3
# 0  value1  value1  value1
# 1  value2  value2  value2
# 2    None  value3  value3
# 3    None    None  value4
```

---

To get a long-form version without nulls, [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the transposed version into `id` and `value` columns and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) only on `value`:

```py
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
   .melt(var_name='id', value_name='value')
   .dropna(subset=['value']))

#       id   value
# 0   key1  value1
# 1   key1  value2
# 4   key2  value1
# 5   key2  value2
# 6   key2  value3
# 8   key3  value1
# 9   key3  value2
# 10  key3  value3
# 11  key3  value4
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to turn this into an "unbalanced" panel ( to get rid of the NAs)? Such as the "ID" column to be the 'key' and value columns with the values of the keys?

Comment: you're welcome. you can `melt` the transposed version to get a long-form version with key/value columns (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to create a dataframe:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

dct = {
    "key1": ["value1", "value2"],
    "key2": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
    "key3": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*dct.values(), fillvalue=np.nan), columns=dct)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     key1    key2    key3
0  value1  value1  value1
1  value2  value2  value2
2     NaN  value3  value3
3     NaN     NaN  value4
```